# Publishing a CS5.5 Made iOS App in CS6 Breaks the App

Tags: flash, air

I've recently upgraded to Flash CS6 from Flash CS5.5. I've been working on a game in CS5.5 and everything was going smoothly. However when I publish the game from CS6, all of the visuals disappear and I'm left with just the stage colour and some small parts of the graphics.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I sincerely hope that I don't have to revert back to CS5.5 every time I want to work with or update my previous releases.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound right at all.

Do you see your game when you test the swf (cmd+Enter)?

Do you see your game when you debug the swf (Debug menu > Debug Movie > (Desktop))?

Do other swf's display correctly when tested? If so perhaps creating a brand new .fla file and moving all code and assets to this new file might be a solution for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. When I export for a .swf, debug, or just test the app it all works perfectly. I've found that the issue is with what processor I'm trying to get the app to run with. I was using GPU mode in Flash CS5.5 and that was fine. I published the app in all modes and with GPU I'm always having the issue and if I use the new "direct" render mode, it works fine.

Comment: So are you OK with just publishing using the Direct method?